# a proof about the relation between differentiable map and linear transformation

Tags: real-analysis

Let $V⊂\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open, connected set and let $f: V→\mathbb{R}^m$ be a differentiable map. Suppose
that there exists a linear transformation $T∈L(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^m)$ such that $Df(x)=T$ for all $ x∈V$. Prove
that there is a $ c∈\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $f(x)=c+T(x)$ for all $ x∈V$.

(I found $Df(x)=DT=T$, is that correct and what this means?)

Comment: The basic idea is that $D(f-T)=0$ on $V$, so $f-T$ is constant on $V$ since it is connected.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x) = f(x)-Tx$. Then we have $D g(x) = 0$ for all $x \in V$. If $x \in V$, then $B(x,r ) \subset V$ for some $r>0$. The mean value theorem gives $\|g(y)-g(x)\| \leq \sup_{\xi \in B(x,r)} \|Dg(\xi)\| \|y-x\| = 0$ for all $y \in B(x,r)$. Hence $g$ is locally constant.

Now choose $x \in V$, and let $W_x = \{ y \in V | g(x) = g(y)\}$. Since $g$ is locally constant, we see that $W_x$ is open, and since $g$ is continuous (since differentiable), we see that $W_x$ is closed. Since $V$ is connected, it follows that $W_x=V$, and hence $g(y) = g(x)$ for all $v \in V$. Hence $f(y) = Ty - (f(x)-Tx) = Ty +c$, with $c = - (f(x)-Tx)$.